# Recommended project structure for modular Java with Gradle, JUnit and Mockito

Tags: java, gradle, junit, mockito, java-module

I'm in the process of trying to migrate a large [code base](https://github.com/EmilyBjoerk/lsml) from Java 8 to modular (JPMS) Java 11, and I'm encountering significant pain and finding consistent advice on project structure and how to use module-info files for actual production projects is hard.

The project in question follows the conventional gradle structure for source and test files:

```
src/main/java/org/abc/...
src/test/java/org/abc/...
```

I have a `module-info.java` file in `src/main/java/module-info.java`, is this the right location? The [quick-start](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start) for modular java and [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-modularity) seems to contradict this; however [other](https://alexkudlick.com/blog/building-modular-java-applications-with-gradle/) [resources](https://sormuras.github.io/blog/2018-09-11-testing-in-the-modular-world.html) do it the way I did.

When trying to run a unit test that looks like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ABCTest {
    @Mock
    public SomeClass mock;

    ...
}
```

I get:

```
Unable to make field public SomeClass mock accessible: module org.abc does not "exports org.abc" 
to module org.mockito
```

which indicates that I need to add `exports org.abc to org.mockito` in my `module-info.java` file but this seems clunky and verbose having to do this for all sub packages in my test tree which aren't even part of the module, and it seems like the wrong place to do it since the tests shouldn't be exported with the release jar.

The seemingly most up to date guidance I [could find](https://sormuras.github.io/blog/2018-09-11-testing-in-the-modular-world.html) suggests adding a `module-info.[test|java]` file to my test tree. What is the difference between these two files (`.java` and `.test`)? I couldn't find any hits on Google explaining this. Also I'm supposedly going to have to copy content from the `main/java/module-info.java` to the `test/java/module-info.test` and keep them in sync? This seems tedious.

I also understand that gradle doesn't have native support for modular java yet and one must rely on plugins for this, what are the "defacto" plugins that one should use?

I'm confused by the information available, it seems contradicting, very low level or not applicable when using gradle. Could some one please provide an example project with conventional source layout using mockito, junit, gradle and modular java (version 9+, preferably 11)?

Comment: Seems the situation is yet unclear. But there are already articles like https://dzone.com/articles/building-java-6-8-libraries-for-jpms-in-gradle. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59117333/how-can-i-set-the-modulemainclass-attribute-of-a-jpms-module-using-gradle

Comment: Even if you solve that one access issue, you will then run up against an *`InvalidModuleDescriptorException`*; caused by the *`xpp3:xpp3_min:1.1.4c`* artifact. JPMS determines that it is an invalid module because it contains a Service Provider configuration file that is malformed. It is one of a few often-encountered artifacts that are the bane of any JPMS project unfortunate enough to have them end up on the module path. The only sane solution is to refactor your application to use a different XML Pull Parser. *StAX* for example. Which is built-in to the JDK within the *`java.xml`* module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle doesn't have built-in out-of-the-box support for JPMS, as you've found out.

Gradle's JPMS policy can be summed up by [*this comment*](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/658#issuecomment-461732835) from one of the Gradle Core Devs...

> > „...*There's no short-term plan to work on jigsaw support, so please don't hold your breath*...“

I've developed [*a plugin that JPMS-enables Gradle and Eclipse*](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.lingocoder.mrjar) though.

[*Here is a simple test project*](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZQyjhkZN1fIJSyHpNRwsexUmdA7WVEQoWGk) that is implemented with Gradle, JPMS, JavaFX 13, JUnit 4 and Mockito. [*The **mrJar***](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.lingocoder.mrjar) JPMS development-enabling plugin is what ties it all together.

You could run the *`:test`* task or the *`:run`* task of that test project from the command line with just raw Gradle. Or follow these steps to use the test project in Eclipse...

1. Import the project into Eclipse

   - [*this screen recording*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9ohr.jpg) might be of some value
2. Execute the *`:eclipse`* task in Eclipse's *`Gradle Tasks`* view

   - this is what triggers the ***Eclipse Modulefication*** feature of ***mrJar***
3. Open the project's properties dialog

   - go to the *`Java Build Path`* properties tab
   - notice the notification in the title bar (*`Not all modules could be found. Click Apply to synchronize`*)
   - click the *`Apply`* button to synchronize the module path
4. Execute the *`:test`* task

   - or alternatively, do *`Run As Gradle Test`* from the *`Package Explorer`* context menu
   - or alternatively again, executing the *`:check`* task is another option that has the same *Eclipse Modulefication* effect as *`:eclipse`*, *`:test`* and *`Run As Gradle Test`*

[*The recording*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9ohr.jpg) might help clarify the steps you need to follow to run the unit tests and the JavaFX application in Eclipse.

Hopefully you will find the attached test project pretty straightforward. But if you get stuck, there are more detailed usage instructions and screen recordings [*in this Gradle Communnity Forum thread*](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/the-mrjar-plugin-v0-0-16-has-been-released-jpms-modules-made-easy/34022/).

I'm also happy to engage with you in that forum thread and clarify anything that might not be obvious in either the video or any of the steps.

---

Also, [*here's a github repository*](https://github.com/lingocoder/mrJarLiSong) with a fully JPMS-enabled copy of your project @EmilyL...

[image: JPMS Modules Made Easy]

Answer (score 1):

My other answer was a response to your „*Could some one please provide an example project with conventional source layout using mockito, junit, gradle and modular java (version 9+, preferably 11)?*“ request.

But you probably also want an answer to the question in your title.

***TL;DR***: Both of the directory structures you've come across are both equally *legal*. But for single module projects, the conventional *`src/main/java`* is all you need.

***The long answer***

The less-often-seen *`src/com.foo.mymodule/io/bar/apackage`* structure is a way to organize your modules nice and neatly in a folder that is the same name as the module. Then the packages of the module go within that flat module name directory as usual.

It is not just a stylistic choice however. There are some practical, technical advantages to organizing modules that less-typical way.

The JPMS *`--module-source-path`* command line option makes it possible to compile several different modules in one shot. So you could have multiple modules organized like so...

```
.
.
└── src
    ├── com.foo.mymodule
    │   ├── module-info.java
    │   └── io
    │       └── bar
    │           └── apackage
    │               ├── *.java
    │               └── ...
    ├── net.other.module
    │   ├── module-info.java
    │   └── org
    │       ├── example
    │       │   └── yadda
    │       │       ├── *.java
    │       │       └── ...
    │       └── another
    │           └── pkg
    │               ├── *.java
    │               └── ...
    ├── mr.jar
    │   ├── module-info.java
    │   └── com
    │       └── lingocoder
    │           └── plugin
    │               ├── *.java
    │               └── ...
    ├── and.so.forth
    └── ...
```

Then *`javac -d mods --module-source-path src ...`* can compile all of the code of all of the modules nested under *`src`*.

It will mirror the directory structures under *`src`* while storing the generated class files in the destination directory (*`mods` in my example*).

For example, all generated class files for the *`net.other.module`* module would be stored in the *`mods/net.other.module`* directory; with the package hierarchy mirrored under that.

Comment: How would this work with tests? Where would you put them? I believe some authors make special test modules, does that make sense, or is there a more 'lightweight' way?